# vscode debugger warning on frozen modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Trying to use the multiprocessing module to run some code. I need to use the python debugger to pass **'-Xfrozen_modules=off'** but using `args` or `pythonArgs` in `launch.json` doesn't seem to work.

```
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off   
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

I passed **'-Xfrozen_modules=off'** using `args` and `pythonArgs` in `launch.json` but that didn't work.

Python 3.11.2

Comment: show a launch.json for a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up added the environment variable "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION" to my launch.json file. For example:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION": "1"
              }
        }
    ]    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not an error, but a warning. This has been solved in May last year [in github](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/861#issuecomment-1067215622).

The resolutions have been mentioned with the warning.

> Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off to python to disable frozen modules.

A workaround is to add this to the configuation in launch.json:

```
"pythonArgs": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"],
```

Please check whether your `launch.json` is correct.

BTW, this issue in github is only for **python3.11.0**, which may also be related to the python version. You can try to use **python3.11.0** for comparison.

If this is a question specific to python 3.11.2, please submit it to developer in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy).

Comment: I have tried that but the debugger launches without the argument and the warning is displayed anyways.

Comment: @a778h6 Could you please try another version of Python?

Answer (score 1):

If you still seeing the above message, try setting

PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1

as env variable

Answer (score 0):

**Hello @a778h6
Welcome to the stackoverflow.**

In regards to your query, you can try below steps. I hope this will help you.

The -Xfrozen_modules=off flag is used to disable the freezing of modules when using the Python interpreter. However, it may not work as expected when using the VS Code debugger.

If you are still seeing the warning message about frozen modules even after passing the -Xfrozen_modules=off flag using the args or pythonArgs configuration in your launch.json file, you can try the following:

1. Make sure that you have restarted your debug session after making
   changes to your launch.json file.
2. Try adding the -Xdev flag to your pythonArgs configuration in
   launch.json. This flag is used to disable the use of optimized .pyc
   files, which can sometimes cause issues when debugging.
3. If you are using an extension like the Python extension for VS Code,
   try updating to the latest version to ensure that you have the
   latest bug fixes and features.
4. If none of the above solutions work, you can try using a different
   debugger, such as pdb or ipdb, which may be better suited for
   debugging code that uses frozen modules.

Keep in mind that frozen modules are read-only and cannot be modified at runtime, so you may need to adjust your debugging approach accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Python extension for vscode and running the latest version.

Comment: I tried adding this as an environment variable but no luck. 
"XFACTOR": "-Xfrozen_modules=off"

Can you provide an example launch.json?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well.